# Regex to find a specific word and merge the following two lines

Tags: c#, regex

I have a C# application where I read a .txt-file looking like this:

- List item
- List item
- Account
- Number
- Five
- List item
- List item
- Account
- Number
- Six
- List item

I need a regex to find the specific word "Account" and then merge the following two lines to get the result

- Account Number Five
- Account Number Six

I have the following regex where I get the first line but how can I merge the following two lines?

```
[\n\r].*Account\s*([^\n]*)
```

Comment: You should have an option to enable multi-lines regex (known as `g` option, but that depends of C# API) and multi-matches. 
And about your regex, you should rather have something like `Account\s*(?:([^\r\n]*)\r\n){2}` with this replace pattern `Account \1 \2`. Be sure to escape correctly back-slashes and to have CRLF `\r\n` end-of-lines from your _.txt_ file.

Comment: Does the text file **literally** look like that? With a bullet on a line? Do a quote section instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if it is possible with one regexp. You can achieve that with two. One for matching, another for replacing newline with space

```
var regex = new Regex(@"Account\r\n\w*\r\n\w*");
var regex_newline = new Regex("(\r\n|\r|\n)");
var matches = regex.Matches(input);
foreach(var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(regex_newline.Replace(match.ToString(), " "));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using `\r\n` and similar hard-coded characters if I can. Below sample worked for me.

```
    static void Main() {
        var str = @"List item 1
List item 2
Account
Number
Five
List item 3
List item 4
Account
Number
Six
List item 5";

        var newStr = Regex.Replace(str, @"^\s*(Account)\s*^\s*(.*?)\s*$\s*^\s*(.*?)\s*$", "$1 $2 $3", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        Console.WriteLine($"Original: \r\n{str}\r\n---------------\r\n");
        Console.WriteLine($"New: \r\n{newStr}\r\n---------------\r\n");
    }
```

Below was the output for it

```
Original:
List item 1
List item 2
Account
Number
Five
List item 3
List item 4
Account
Number
Six
List item 5
---------------

New:
List item 1
List item 2
Account Number Five
List item 3
List item 4
Account Number Six
List item 5
---------------
```

Regex Explanation:

```
^\s*(Account)\s*        - Match from start of line followed by Account. If there are white spaces around account, then eat them up too.
^\s*(.*?)\s*$\s*        - Match from start of line, followed by optional white-spaces, followed by capturing all text on that line, followed by optional white-spaces, and then end-of-line. The last \s* eats up the end-of-line character(s)
^\s*(.*?)\s*$           - Same as above explanation, except that we don't want to eat up the end-of-line character(s) at the end
```

Replacement:

```
"$1 $2 $3"              - the 3 items we captured in the above regex with a space in between them.
```

Regex Options:

```
MultiLine               - ^ and $ character will match beginning and end of any line and not just the start and end of the string
```